# how can I make a bold horizontal rule under each chapter name

Tags: sectioning, rules

I use report documentclass

like this

```
           CHAPTER 1
         Introduction
----------------------------
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2):

The `titlesec` package has lots of examples of this sort of chapter heading. Here's one to get you started:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\bfseries\Large\filcenter}
  {\Large\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}
  {1pc}
  {\Huge}
  [\vspace{1pc}{\titlerule[2pt]}]
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]